# refresh a specific div on jsp page and not whole page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jquery

i want to refresh a div on the basis of input ...here is a sample code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="1" value="1" onClick="javaScript:update('1');"/>
<input type="button" id="2" value="2" onClick="javaScript:update('2');"/>
<%
int value=1;
%>
<div id="refresh">
<%=value %>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function update(input)
{
        value=input;
        alert(value);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so here is what i want when page loads it will print 1 as value is initialized with 1 but if i click 2 i want that div to print 2 whose value gets updated in update function of java script ...i don't want to refresh whole page just want to refresh that div ...i don't want to use JQUERY.load as it loads the whole page in div i just want to refresh that div

Comment: (OT) why not encode in UTF8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function update(input)
{
        $("#refresh").html(input)
}
```

That should be all you need

`.html()` is the jQuery function that changes the innerHTML of an element.

For ajax you can look at the jquery docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [this is a nice looking example for jQUery + php](http://www.jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return)

Comment: what if i want this value to be input of a database function...as with value 1 it will show different record and with value 2 it will show different record ....so when page will load it will show record associated with value 1 when but when i click button 2 will it show record associated with value 2 instead of record 1 using this function?

Comment: then you're going to need to make an ajax call to the server.  You can look into `$.ajax()`.  But you'll need to set up a PHP page to actually make the database call.  Client side code can't interact directly with a server-side database.

Comment: can you help me a bit with this ...i don;t have any idea of ajax any tutorial or example?

Comment: @user2137186 refer this link for your query (https://codebridgeplus.com/pagination-in-jsp/)